# python logging does not release file

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have been using logging and notice that after first compile, the output file for logging hangs, and I cannot remove it till I close IDLE.

I believe that I should "close" logging before the compilation finish, but don't know how to do that with the way that I am using logging:

```
LOGFILE = os.path.join(backup_folder,'test.log')
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOGFILE,level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
logging.debug('test')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So seems that I have found a way by adding in the end:

```
logging.shutdown()
```

This instruction close all handlers that was openned.